# Contouring in ArcGIS from raster file yielded rectangular contours

Tags: arcgis-desktop, contour

Why does Contouring in ArcGIS using Contour tool in ArcGIS from raster file yielded rectangular contours?

The attached image of contour is shown below

[image]

The contours shows a rectangular gridded contours which doesn't look like contours

I have also tried the same with QGIS and get the similar results.

Comment: Applying a low pass filter to convert the integer DEM to float has been the solution for this for at least 25 years. The current documentation is https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/filter.htm

Answer (score 3):

My hypothesis is that this comes from the input data, which is probably produced by the resampling of a coarse resolution dataset into a finer resolution one. Also, you seem to seek very precise height intervals with respect to the range of values in your area. A quick check would be the computation of the slope of your image (the same pattern would be visible). In practice, it means that you are not working at the optimal spatial resolution. You could make the results look nicer with several low pass filters on the input data, but it will not make the data more correct. If you have the original coarse resolution data, you could also convert the raster to points then use an interpolation method to achieve a finer resolution.